# mp3 file doesn't play in Facebox

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebox

I am using Facebox. I have to play mp3files in Facebox. I included facebox.js and facebox.css

My view code is:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();
    }
</script>

$res= explode('/',$val['audio_file']);

<a href="<?=base_url().'uploads/'.$val['audio_file'];?>" rel="facebox"><?=$res['1'];?></a>
```

I have to play this mp3 file in Facebox. Is it possible?

I have linked the mp3 file in anchor tag, then can I play that file in a facebox. Now it plays in big screen.

Comment: care to give details how it doesn't play? does the plugin load? errors, etc?

Comment: Bit confused on what does what..Your first snippet creates an anchor to what? site_url('controller/method') gives something like http://www.yoursite.com/index.php/controller/method, which is not suited for linking files. While, in your last snippet, window.location (what's that for??) is given an url to a file instead...where are you redirecting to? Also, I don't think that "facebox" plugin is capable of pleaying mp3s

Comment: i have edited the code..i have linked the mp3 file in anchor tag..then can i play that file in a facebox..now it plays in big screen

Comment: You're missing a closing `);` at the end of your jQuery snippet. Were you getting any JS errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include it in view

```
<script type="javascript">

        $('#play').live('click', function(e) {                                           
        e.preventDefault();
        link=this.href;  
        jQuery.facebox({ ajax: link });
        });

        </script>

<a id="play" href="<?=site_url('admin/test/playmp3/'.$val['id']);?>"><?=$res['1'];?></a>
```

Include it in controller

```
function playmp3($id)
{
$this->data['mp3']  = $this->test_model->getmp3($id);
$this->load->vars($this->data);
echo $this->load->view( $this->config->item('APP_template_dir').'admin/playmp3_view');
}
```

Create a new page playmp3_view and include it

```
    <div style="">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="<?=base_url().$this->config->item('APP_assets_admin').'/'.$this->config->item('APP_js');?>/player_mp3.swf" width="200" height="20">
   <param name="movie" value="<?=base_url().$this->config->item('APP_assets_admin').'/'.$this->config->item('APP_js');?>/player_mp3.swf" />
   <param name="FlashVars" value="mp3=<?=base_url().'uploads/'.$mp3->audio_file?>" /></object>
    </div>
```